# how to get mysql value into echod form?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

im echoing a form for a paypal buy it now button.

In the amount hidden input i need to put

```
$info['price']
```

This is a mysql value

I have tried it like this

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='$info['price']'>";
```

But im now getting a blank screen.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `type='hidden'` mean it's hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to write as follows

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='".$info['price']."' />";
```

Comment: thank you very much, i'll accept this answer after the 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Try as

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$info['price'].'">';
```

Hidden fields will not be shown so you may need to see the source code on browser to check if the values are properly getting set for the field.